# Artin product rings example

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

[image: Artin example]

In the above picture of example 11.6.3, my questions are:

1.) why is both the order of $eR’$ and $e’R’$ $11$? Does it have something to do with $11$ being prime and that $122$ = $11 \times 11$?

2.) How do we know $eR’$ and $e’R’$ are isomorphic to $F_{11}$

Thanks!

Comment: I can't see the whole thing

Comment: Fixed it @D_S, sorry about that

Comment: I may write a detailed answer, but all this should follow from the Chinese remainder theorem

Comment: The quotient of $\mathbb F_{11}[t]$ by the ideal generated by $t - 5$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb F_{11}$.  The isomorphism is given by sending $f(t)$ to $f(5)$.

Comment: we haven't actually done the chinese remainder theorem. we do have the division algorithm though, if that helps

Comment: why are u considering that quotient using the ideal (t-5)? isnt the quotient to consider here $F_{11}$/$(t^3 -2)$?

Comment: No, it is $\mathbb F[t]$ modulo $(t^2 - 3) = (t+5)(t-5)$.

Comment: a full answer would be appreciated it, not quite sure how this all comes together

Comment: Is $F_{11}[t]$/$(t-5)$ isomorphic to $F_{11}$ since we are essentially adding an element, $x$, with the property that $x-5 =0$, but such an element already exists in $F_{11}$, namely the number 5. So the quotient operation does nothing in this case? Hence isomorphic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the text, it seems the author is using the following very elementary argument.

We have two idempotents $e,e'$ such that $e+e'=1$, and hence also that $ee'=0=e'e$ (seen for example by multiplying $e+e'=1$ on the left or right by $e$). Since the ring $R'$ is commutative, it follows that $R'\cong R'e\times R'e'$. Now $R'e$ and $R'e'$ are both non-trivial rings, with respective units $e,e'$, and $11^2$ has only one proper factorisation, so necessarily $|R'e|=11=|R'e'|$. Finally, since 11 is prime, $R'e$ is generated as an additive group by the unit $e$. Thus the ring homomorphism $\mathbb Z\to R'e$ is onto, and yields an isomorphism $\mathbb F_{11}=\mathbb Z/(11)\xrightarrow\sim R'e$.

The more advanced way of seeing this goes by way of the Chinese Remainder Theorem, which in one form says that if we have a (commutative) ring $R$ and ideals $I,J$ such that $I+J=R$, then $I\cap J=IJ$ and there is an isomorphism $R/IJ\xrightarrow\sim R/I\times R/J$.

For your question, we would take $R'=\mathbb F_{11}[t]/(t^2-3)$, which is what we mean when we say we abstractly/artificially adjoin a square root of 3. In $\mathbb F_{11}[t]$ we have the ideals $I=(t-5)$ and $J=(t+5)$, so that $I+J=\mathbb F_{11}[t]$, and also $\mathbb F_{11}[t]/I\cong\mathbb F_{11}$ via the map $t\mapsto 5$. Similarly for $J$, and so the Chinese Remainder Theorem gives
$$ R'\cong\mathbb F_{11}[t]/IJ\cong\mathbb F_{11}[t]/I\times\mathbb F_{11}[t]/J\cong \mathbb F_{11}\times\mathbb F_{11}. $$
It is easy to check that $e$ is sent to $(0,1)$ and $e'$ is sent to $(1,0)$.

Comment: Thanks! And how did u know $e$ generates $R'e$?

Comment: Would that be since there is only one homomorphism, $\phi$, from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $eR'$, and since $e$ is the multiplicative identity of $eR'$, then we must have $1$ -> $e$ via  $\phi$. Hence since the kernel of this map is (11), we have that since $1$ generates $\mathbb{Z}$/(11), that implies $e$ generates $eR'$, does that work? -- Note that kernel must be (11) since we must mod out by some ideal in order to shrink $\mathbb{Z}$ to order 11. Since ideals of $\mathbb{Z}$ are principle ideals of the form (n) ,we have (11) is the only ideal that shrinks $\mathbb{Z}$ to order 11. So kernel = (11)

Comment: That argument works but really I was just thinking that, as an additive group, $R'e$ has eleven elements, so must be cyclic and every non-zero element is a generator.

Comment: Thanks. In the second part, is the map $t$-> $5$ an isomorphism since $\phi$: $F_{11}[t]$ -> $F_{11}$ is surjective via the map $t$ -> $5$, and so the kernel is all polynomials with $5$ as a root, and so $(t-5)$ divides every f $\in$ K and, for $g \in K$, $g = fq + r$ with remainder of degree $0$ and $5$ as a root => $r$ = $0$. Hence the kernel is the principle ideal $(t-5)$ and so $F_{11}$/$(t-5)$ is isomorphic to the image of $\phi$, which is $F_{11}$. That work?

Comment: That’s correct.